# Nuget package install resulted in --> c# - cs7003 unexpected use of an unbound generic name

Tags: c#, razor, model-view-controller

today i was trying to add Ninect.web.common to my project but surprisingly i received a strange error for the first time:
My project is running well and no build error at all, but as i try to add this package, i receive this error:

********** Action *********

```
public ActionResult Index()

    {
      ......
      return View((object)totalValue);

    }
```

************** View **********

```
@model decimal



<div> 

    Total value:@Model

 </div>
```

Error   CS7003  Unexpected use of an unbound generic name

Error   CS0037  Cannot convert null to 'decimal' because it is a non-nullable

Two errors are referencing the first line of view!

Comment: what is the type of `totalValue` variable ?

Comment: totalValue is calculated in a function and i also gave it a direct value. no problem with the value, the project is run with no error,  only when i try to install the package i receive such an error

Comment: i think the problem is some kind of incompatibility between packages of Ninject: when i try to install ninjct.web.common after Ninject, i recieve these errors with an error of incompatibility:--> Unable to resolve dependencies. 'Ninject 3.3.0' is not compatible with 'Ninject.Web.Common 3.2.3 constraint: Ninject (>= 3.2.0 && < 3.3.0)'.

Answer (score 0):

I removed previously installed Ninject packages and installed all of them form scratch!

Installation completed and now i can use Ninject in my project.
This error appears again if i try to update packeges!